# Solar panel as day/night switch for a load

Tags: mosfet, lipo, led-driver, solar-energy

I'm using off-the-shelf components to power a buck/boost LED driver and charge a battery from a 6V solar panel.

To power the LED driver from the battery at dusk only, would I have to use a MOSFET like shown below, or is another component needed; or do I need something very different altogether?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I think I have understood that I need a PMOS in my case (instead of a transistor like in [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/oskay/2963306745/) PV solar panel darkness detection circuit). And a resistor between PV solar panel and PMOS gate. Am I understanding this correctly or not? If yes, how would I calculate Rg?

[image: Updated schematic]

Answer (score 1):

The way most flag LED spots turn on only after dark is a voltage comparator that switches on when the solar panel output drops below about 1.2V or so.  The voltage output from a solar panel decreases as it loses its light source.  You would need the specs from the solar panel to figure out the precise trigger voltage.  Or lacking that 1.2v is a decent rule of thumb.

Comment: Monitoring the panel's output voltage does not work very well.  The panel's output voltage is dependent on time or day, the sun's current irradiation level (clouds and date), and the instantaneous charge current.  My 12V panel's voltage is currently 0.27V at 4:00pm in Tampa with a fixed 28Ω load.   A 1.2V cutoff is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a battery charger with maximum power point tracking (MPPT).

I am currently evaluating the Texas Instruments [bq24650](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24650.pdf)
I purchased two panels, a "5 W" and "10 W".  This equates to more like 2.5 W and 5 W panels.  5 and 10 W likely applies when the panel is located in a desert on the equator.
Both are "12V" panels.
The actual voltage depends on the level of the sun's irradiation and the load.
I am characterizing the 10 W panel today with a fixed load (28 Ω, 25 W resistor).
I live in Tampa.  This morning was clear, this afternoon is mostly cloudy.
At noon the output voltage was about 12V until about 1:00pm when it started getting cloudy.
Right now, 2:00pm and cloudy, the voltage of this 12V panel is 1.3V.
Late morning the voltage was averaging about 12V.  But if I were to lower the load resistance, the voltage would decrease.  If I were to in crease the resistance the voltage would increase.
This is why a MPPT charger is better than a buck boost.

[image]

A MPPT charger varies the load by regulating the amount of charge current.  If the voltage drops, the charge current is reduced until the PV voltage is back up at it's ideal operating point (maximum power for the current wattage).

Look at the solar panels as a power (watts) source rather than a voltage source.

---

> To power the LED driver from the battery at dusk only

You need a µController with a real time clock and calculate dusk based on your latitude, longitude, and date.  I use an ATtiny 417 because it has a DAC output to change the power point setting (MPPSET on the bq24650).

I see you are using a Cree XP-L.  These are used when you need a lot of light from a small area like a street light. They have okay efficacy at 107 lm/W. that 3000K and CRI90 is costing you some lumens.

When you have a battery powered LED project you want the most efficient LED to extend battery life.  The Samsung 3000K 90 CRI, SPMWHD32AMD7XAU0S0  has an efficacy of 173 lm/W which would save you 80%. Also it would run much cooler and would need no heat sink.  The Cree LED will run very hot.  Without significant thermal management you can only run them at maybe 300 mA.  The higher the temperature will cost more lumens.  The LM301B LEDs will take substantially more PCB real estate but is worth it if it's within the project's requirements.

I would recommend the Bridgelux EB Gen2 or Samsung F-series Gen3 strips. Bridgelux has a "tunable" "Vesta" strip with 2700 K and 5000K LEDs.  Digikey has them for $6 for a 280 mm x 31 mm strip.  I use them just for the 2700K. No heat sink required.  Although they can get hot if both strings are run a full power.

---

There are many choices for solar chargers.  There are some that are specifically targeted for a single cell Li-ion battery.  Search Digikey for "solar" to get an idea about the choices.  This link is to Digikey's eval boards associated with solar:
[Digikey solar evaluation boards](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/development-boards-kits-programmers/evaluation-and-demonstration-boards-and-kits/787?FV=ffe00313&quantity=0&ColumnSort=-1000007&page=1&k=solar&pageSize=50)
see also PMIC - Battery Chargers, PMIC - Voltage Regulators, and PMIC - Special Purpose and PMIC - Power Management.

It is not 4:00pm and overcast.  The voltage is now 0.3V.

---

A few years ago I bought four 100 W panels to power some grow lights.  The $400 panels quickly grew to over $1,200.

As the problems would arise I'd add more components.  This is where I gave up:

[image]

I have now reduced the above to just the Mean Well HLG-185H-54B.

---

Solar power is only useful where utility electric is not available. My electric costs about 9¢ a kWh.  There is no way to recoup the cost of the panels and batteries when electric is is so cheap.  If you have a 100 W panel you can get maybe 50 watts 6 hours on a clear sunny day.  Much less depending on your latitude and weather patterns.

The reason I am working on solar again is I need power where electric will not be available.  For the past few years I had been working on LED grow lights for the horticulture research dept. at Florida University.  I just moved from Gainesville to Tampa.  I work out of my house and know no one in this city.  I need to get out. I am going to sell grow lights, lettuce, tomatoes, and herbs at the farmers market, 1 mile from my house. Tampa has a big farmers market in Ybor, 1 mile from my house,  on Saturdays from 9am to 3pm, peak daylight solar hours being 10 am to 2 pm. I will charge the lead acid batteries with conventional electric and use the solar panels to help keep the batteries from going dead and attract attention.

I am doing research into growing food as efficiently as possible under LEDs. The plants I will sell are a by product of this research.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping this could be accomplished easier; I'm good in biology but no EE (it's going to be an autonomous insect attractor, top branch of a high tree). I thought about using https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tpl5110-power-timer-breakout/ but then I've seen others using only the PV solar panel as "trigger" and Adafruit's solar/charger PCB. Phew, that seems more complex than I first thought.

Comment: The Adafruit charger will work, just not very efficiently when compared to an MPPT.  The important thing is for the boost converter's input range minimum voltage be as low as possible.  It's now overcast and the voltage is 0.3V at 4:00pm.

Comment: Using the PV solar panel seemed "simpler" and more "clever", but if I can minimise power consumption, I may better use a Trinket µC and that power timer PCB, and simply set the thing to a fixed hour, running until the battery is depleted and cuts itself off.

Comment: Yeah, I know there could be clouds, precipitation, the twig twisting the set-up away from the sun. But intermittent dusk/night illumination would be better than none. The top twigs are lightweight and long and if I use a heavy high capacity battery, the whole thing becomes an inverted pendulum in the worst case.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean about the simple and easy.  I had exactly the same thoughts on a slightly grander scale.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Well, I give the PMOS idea a try and see how that goes.